# How to asynchronously use _.some

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Is there a way to asynchronously use [_.some()](http://underscorejs.org/#some)? I've got the below code snippet that I'm trying to switch to an asynchronous method to prevent it from causing timeout issues.

```
DLClear = function( obj, squarePt ) {

    var wallPaths = findObjs( {
         _type  : 'path',
         _pageid: obj.get('pageid'),
        layer   : 'walls'
    } );

    var landingPt    = [ obj.get('left'), obj.get('top'), 1 ];
    var wallSegments = PathMath.toSegments( wallPaths );
    var squareSeg    = [ landingPt, squarePt ];

    var blocked = _.some( wallSegments, function( wallSeg ) {
        return PathMath.segmentIntersection( squareSeg, wallSeg );
    } );
    return !blocked;
},
```

The platform I'm writing for is using javascript ES7 so async/await is usable.

Any and all help is appreciated,

Scott

Comment: Asynchronous code won't help you here because your `DLClear` function (and `_.some`) are not IO-bound, but a "busy" function. If your code is taking too long to execute in your environment it suggests you're using an inefficient algorithm. What does your `segmentIntersection` function do? How big is the `wallSegments` array?

Comment: This is for a script for a virtual table top (VTT) gaming platform. segmentIntersection determines if the segments passed to it intersect at any point. The size of the wallSegments array is not fixed. It depends on how many wall segments the user has created on the VTT, so could be 1 entry or could be a couple hundred or thous and (ok thousand's probably hyperbole). I know that _.some() is not what I'll wind up using, but is there a way I could switch it to using something like _.defer() to wait fro the call stack to finish before running?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [async](http://caolan.github.io/async/) library that designed for use with Node.js and for this case .each function will help you.

Comment: Unfortunately that library is not available on the platform, and I can't install additional libraries.

Comment: @ScottCasey What platform? If you have specific requirements it's probably best to provide specific info, e.g., the platform may provide some form of service worker or spawning if the issue is you don't want to block a UI.

Comment: @DaveNewton The platform is the Roll20 API

Comment: @ScottCasey Doesn't that run in the browser?

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes, It's all browser based. You can run custom scripts though to add functionality.

Comment: @ScottCasey If it's in a browser you could [use a worker to offload work](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42800542/918910).